# SELECT sales by user pairs

Tags: sql, select

I have a Session table

```
    UserId    SessionId
    1         a
    2         a
    1         b
    4         b
    2         c
    3         c
```

And another sales table where the sales are tied to a `SessionID`. I would like to get the sales by unique pairs of users from the `Session` table without having to use a cursor.

Comment: could you include sample data from the sales table and the expected output?

Comment: You want to see it for every possible combination of users?

Comment: @JNK: Not every possible combination, just the ones existing already in the Session table.

Comment: makes sense, and I think Quassnoi has you covered now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  ss1.userid, ss2.userid, SUM(sales)
FROM    session ss1
JOIN    session ss2
ON      ss2.sessionid = ss1.sessionid
        AND ss2.userid < ss1.userid
JOIN    sales s
ON      s.sessionid = ss1.sessionid
GROUP BY
        ss1.userid, ss2.userid
```